# EF5 Grdiview only Count & ReadOnly

Tags: frameworks, entity, datasource

In Entity Framework When I add Drag from Datasource the grid view only shows Count & Is Read Only Column, I have also tried manually assigning datsource but still not working.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried and are having difficulty with.  What is the output that you are getting and what are you looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Through some researh I have found a solution.

BTW I am using code first.

In the parent entity I changed the child property from list to ObservableCollection.
I also added the namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel to my class.

Old:`Public Overridable Property PageElements As List(Of PageElement)`

New:`Public Overridable Property PageElements As ObservableCollection(Of PageElement)`

Delete your existing datasource (and controls from the form).  Then recreate your datasource drag to the form.

You may need to create a class called ObservableListSource and use that instead of ObservableCollection, but it seems to have cleared up the original problem so far.

Here a suggested definition for the ObservableListSource I found elsewhere on the web.

```
Public Class ObservableListSource(Of T As Class)
     Inherits ObservableCollection(Of T)
     Implements IListSource
     Private _bindingList As IBindingList

    Private ReadOnly Property ContainsListCollection() As Boolean Implements IListSource.ContainsListCollection
         Get
             Return False
         End Get
     End Property

    Private Function GetList() As IList Implements IListSource.GetList
         Return If(_bindingList, (InlineAssignHelper(_bindingList, Me.ToBindingList())))
     End Function
     Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
         target = value
         Return value
     End Function
EndCLass
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (EF6):

Add an `ObservableListSource` class to the project and change namespace

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis; 
using System.Data.Entity; 

namespace WinApp 
{ 
public class ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource 
    where T : class 
{ 
    private IBindingList _bindingList; 

    bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection { get { return false; } } 

    IList IListSource.GetList() 
    { 
        return _bindingList ?? (_bindingList = this.ToBindingList()); 
    } 
}
```

}

After that open `yourModel.tt` file

- Find and replace the two occurrences of `“ICollection”` with `“ObservableListSource”` (lines `296` and `484`).
- Find and replace the first occurrence of `“HashSet”` with `“ObservableListSource”` ( Line `50`).
- Do not replace the second occurrence of HashSet found later in the code.

Comment: Any reason why this problem in EF6?? I find it very strange.